# What is the difference between the different formulations used in describing how a hadith was transmitted?

Tags: terminology, uloom-al-hadith, definitions

In hadith books we may read in the narrator chain how and via whom a hadith was transmitted. I wonder if different formulations indicate different ways of transmission here some examples we may find:

> أخبرنا (we have been informed by)   see for example [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/68/73)
>   حدثنا ("..." informed us) see for example [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/120)
>   قرأت على (I've read/recitet in front of "...") like [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim/33/135) were a narrator has read in front of imam Malik a ahadith (Malik) has transmitted via Nafi'i etc.
>   بلغنا ("..." reached us) see for example [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim/19/27) in Sahih Muslim.
>   سمعت (I've heard "...") like [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/61/80) in Sahih al-Bukhari
>   روينا (we have transmitted)  -input from III-AK-III's comment on my former [Meta post](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3351/13438)-.

I guess there are many more formulations and wordings (for example the two first may appear in singular, maybe using the passive form is possible) that are used.

My question is,
is there a difference in the way a hadith was transmitted if the transmitter (narrator) uses a different wording
or
how significant is the formulation to be able to check whether a hadith was transmitted in a certain manner?